# The termination predicate in Coq

Tags: coq

Consider a predicate that models an evaluation relation. The relation will stop with either true or false, so that's why I want the values of my chains to be either a configuration or a boolean:

```
Inductive compile_step :
  conf_type + bool -> conf_type + bool -> Prop
```

I know the evaluation terminates and I want to prove it formally. So I define a terminating predicate:

```
Inductive terminating {A} (r: A -> A -> Prop) (c': A) :=
| TStep : (forall c1, r c' c1 -> terminating r c1) ->
          terminating r c'.
```

And try to prove it:

```
Lemma compiling_terminates (c': A):
  terminating compile_step c'.
```

Now, what is my surprise that Coq becomes crazy. Here the wise thing to do is to apply TStep and solve this goal:

> (H) c' ⟹ c1 implies terminating compile_step c1

Here is where problems start:

1. inversion H:

> Error: Inversion would require case analysis on sort Set which is not
>   allowed for inductive definition compile_step.

2. destruct H:

> Error: Case analysis on sort Set is not allowed for inductive
>   definition compile_step.

3. induction H:

> Error: Cannot find the elimination combinator compile_step_rec, the
>   elimination of the inductive definition compile_step on sort Set is
>   probably not allowed.

The error reproduces itself at deeper levels of the hierarchy.

Is there a simple explanation for this? Is there a simple solution?

Perhaps [this](https://github.com/coq/coq/issues/5342) is informative for some of you.

Comment: Try explicitly putting `terminating` in `Prop` (`Inductive terminating {A} (r: A -> A -> Prop) (c': A): Prop := ...`). The problem is that you can't use elimination on a term in a `Prop` to produce a term for a `Set`.

Comment: @SCappella that did it

Comment: Just to clarify, `Prop` is built with the idea that it should be computationally irrelevant, so Coq cannot allow you to do a case analysis on a proof of a proposition to build something meaningful that would compute. So Coq doesn't become crazy, it's just telling you to watch out for what you mean to do.

Comment: thanks for the clarification! @ThéoWinterhalter